# row in index value in grid always taking from zero onwards..how to get row index value properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever am executing grid the value of row id it is taking as `0` so `delete` and `edit` operations are not performing well.

Any one please help me. Thanks in advance

```
protected void Grd_View_RowCommand(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        int rowid = 1;
         rowid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Session["rowid"]= rowid;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CustomerProfMain where CustomerCode='" +rowid+ "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dt=ds.Tables[0];
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CustomerName"].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text=dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
        TextBox3.Text=dt.Rows[0]["TellNo"].ToString();
        TextBox4.Text=dt.Rows[0]["FaxNo"].ToString();
        TextBox5.Text=dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
        Button1.Text = "Update";
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int rowid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Session["rowid"] = rowid;
        // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from CustomerProfMain where CustomerCode='"+rowid+"' ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //sda.Fill(ds);
        //dt = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CommandSource` property. Please try

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer; 
int rowIndex    = gvr.RowIndex;
```

You will get row index as in your question

```
 int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

If you are using  `<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />` or  `<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Save"  CommandName="Edit" />`

But the best approach is using the `CommandArgument` you have to set it from aspx:

```
CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'
```

then you will get RowIndex as follows:

```
int RowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Please refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/250105/commandArgument-in-gridview-asp-net) or
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494074/3089494) to know `CommandArgument` in the `Gridview`