# rowindex always starting from zero onwards...why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code ..while editing and deleting row index always taking zero on-wards...delete command not at all working....if i try to edit anything only 2nd row onwards its working...delete command not at all working..i think it is because of row index..please any one help me thanks in advance....

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class Manager_Payments : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection("Data Source=sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=isoqrmssys;User ID=sa;password=123456;Integrated Security=True");

    Business BL = new Business();

     //protected Int64 stf_ID, vmember;
    //protected DateTime SRDT;
   private System.Drawing.Color a;
    string myStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadgridview();
    }

    private void loadgridview()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CustomerProfMain", con);
        //string sql = "SELECT * FROM CustomerProfMain";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        //return ds.Tables[0];
        Grd_View.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Grd_View.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }


    protected void Grd_View_RowCommand(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {

                int index = Grd_View.SelectedIndex;
                if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
                {
                    //string RowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                   // Session["rowid"] = RowIndex;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CustomerProfMain where CustomerCode='" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "'", con);
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    con.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    dt=ds.Tables[0];
                    TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CustomerName"].ToString();
                    TextBox2.Text=dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
                    TextBox3.Text=dt.Rows[0]["TellNo"].ToString();
                    TextBox4.Text=dt.Rows[0]["FaxNo"].ToString();
                    TextBox5.Text=dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
                    Button1.Text = "Update";

                }
                if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
                {
                    int RowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                   Session["rowid"] = RowIndex;
                   // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from CustomerProfMain where CustomerCode='" + RowIndex + "' ", con);
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();


                }
              }
    protected void Grd_View_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Grd_View_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Grd_View_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button1.Text == "Add")
        {
            string myStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
            con.Open();
            string sql = string.Empty;
            sql = "insert into CustomerProfMain(CustomerName,Address,TellNo,FaxNo,Email) values('" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox2.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox3.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox4.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox5.Text.Trim() + "') ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            TextBox3.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox5.Text = "";
            Button1.Text = "Add";
            loadgridview();
        }
        if (Button1.Text == "Update")
        {
            string myStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
            con.Open();
            string sql = string.Empty;
            sql = "update CustomerProfMain set CustomerName='" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "',Address='" + TextBox2.Text.Trim() + "',TellNo='" + TextBox3.Text.Trim() + "',FaxNo='" + TextBox4.Text.Trim() + "',Email='" + TextBox5.Text.Trim() + "' where CustomerCode='" + Session["rowid"] + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            TextBox3.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox5.Text = "";
            Button1.Text = "Add";
            loadgridview();
        }

    }



}



"<asp:GridView ID="Grd_View" ShowFooter="True" runat="server" OnRowEditing="Grd_View_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     DataKeyNames="CustomerCode" cellpadding="4" OnRowCommand="Grd_View_RowCommand"                  GridLines="None" 
                    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="style2" ForeColor="#333333" Width="569px" OnRowDataBound="Grd_View_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Grd_View_RowDeleting">
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#555555" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCode" HeaderText="CustomerCode" InsertVisible="False"
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerCode" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" SortExpression="CustomerName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TellNo" HeaderText="TellNo" SortExpression="TellNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FaxNo" HeaderText="FaxNo" SortExpression="FaxNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" SelectText="Edit" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" SelectText="Delete" />

                    </Columns>
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#777777" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#555555" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

                </asp:GridView>
```

"

Comment: Please be aware that your code has SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Are you sure CustomerCode in the database is same as the rowindex of the grid .? Can you please show the aspx code for grid...?

Comment: Fool has a point, my answer assumes everything is straight and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466172(v=vs.110).aspx) is supposed to help with "SQL injection vulnerabilities" - paqogomez.

Comment: @chrish549 Please don't post "aspx code as answer" . Edit your question and post it too. If you want to  get `e.CommandArgument` as `CustomerCode` you have to set it. You are not setting it in code behind as i can see your cs code. So i want to know how you are setting it in your aspx code. Ex :`CommandArgument='<%# Eval('CustomerCode') %>' ` . Anyway i cannot see your aspx as an answere too :-)

Comment: am not able to set code in comment box sir...

Comment: @chrish "am not able to set code in comment box sir..." can you elaborate

Comment: Can you see edit button below your question. Edit your question .post your code. no need to put  code in comment box ....[Please refer this too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8494074/3089494) And if you are not setting `CommandArgument` you will get `e.CommandArgument` as integers in ascending order starting from zero

Comment: ok sir i inserted aspx code sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your grid view with this code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Grd_View" ShowFooter="True" runat="server" OnRowEditing="Grd_View_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="CustomerCode" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="Grd_View_RowCommand" GridLines="None"
                AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="style2" ForeColor="#333333" Width="569px" OnRowDataBound="Grd_View_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Grd_View_RowDeleting">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#555555" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCode" HeaderText="CustomerCode" InsertVisible="False"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerCode" />

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" SortExpression="CustomerName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TellNo" HeaderText="TellNo" SortExpression="TellNo" />

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#777777" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#555555" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

            </asp:GridView>
```

You didn't set `CommandArgument` here we set it as `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerCode")%>'` to your edit button and delete button

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following...on page load bind the grid ONLY if it's not a postback...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        loadgridview();
}
```

Then re-bind the grid at the end of the command event handler, I'll remove some data access logic for clarity...

```
protected void Grd_View_RowCommand(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            int index = Grd_View.SelectedIndex;
            if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {
               //...
               loadgridview();
            }
            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
               //...
               loadgridview();
            }
          }
```

Comment: similar thing happening sir...still row index value showing "0"

Comment: since, you have NOT posted the pertinent HTML I have to ask....what's `e.CommandArgument`? and who is triggering that command?

Comment: read the msdn link I posted in the comments for my answer `e.CommandArgument` is supposed to be set by the programmer as a string.

Comment: @Leo oh yeah, I guess you where already asking what he set it to

Answer (score 0):

Try this and Set GridView's AutoPostback property to true

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        loadgridview();
    }
}
```